# remove entire rows from df if the word occurs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

list of stowwords:

stop_w = ["in", "&", "the", "|", "and", "is", "of", "a", "an", "as", "for", "was"]

df:

| words | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| the company | 10 |
| green energy | 9 |
| founded in | 8 |
| gases for | 8 |
| electricity | 5 |

I would like to remove entire row if it contains ANY of given stopwords, in this example output should be:

| words | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| green energy | 9 |
| electricity | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` character has a meaning, it means `or` in python's terms, so you need to escape that meaning in order to use it in your stop words list. You escape that with a backslash `\` (see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp#:%7E:text=To%20insert%20characters%20that%20are,character%20you%20want%20to%20insert.))

Having said that you can do:

```
stop_w = ["in", "&", "the", "\|", "and", "is", "of", "a", "an", "as", "for", "was"]
df.loc[~df['words'].str.contains('|'.join(stop_w))]
```

prints:

```
          words  frequency
1  green energy          9
4   electricity          5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create sub_df like this:

```
sub_df = df[df.words.str not in stop_w]
```

Or get ids of rows i want to remove:

```
idx = df[df.words.str in stop_w].index
df.drop(idx)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html